# Shopware 6.5 nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, shopware6

I run some shopware 6.4.x shops.

However, these are running on an nginx server.

Since I would like to continue running nginx, I wanted to ask if there are already configuration templates for nginx.

I have tried to rewrite the .htaccess into a nginx config.

But I didn't manage to translate this part correctly:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

Answer (score 2):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;

    client_max_body_size 128M;

    root /var/www/html/public;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    
    location = /sw-domain-hash.html {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|ico|png|svg|webp|html)$ {
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";

        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;

        tcp_nodelay off;
        ## Set the OS file cache.
        open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
        open_file_cache_valid 45s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
        open_file_cache_errors off;
    }
    
    # Shopware install / update
    # new for Shopware 6.5
    location /shopware-installer.phar.php {
        try_files $uri /shopware-installer.phar.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /recovery/install {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri /recovery/install/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /recovery/update/ {
        location /recovery/update/assets {
        }
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite . /recovery/update/index.php last;
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $fcgi_https;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        http2_push_preload on;
    }
}
```